# Forms Authentication (stay logged in during app domain recycles or restarts)

Tags: nancy

I'm attempting to configure my Nancy application to stay logged it and not have to re-authenticate when the application pool restarts or IIS restarts. From what I read I need to specify the CryptographyConfiguration on the FormsAuthenticationConfiguration which I have done in the RequestStartup method.

Is there something I am missing? I'm provided my code example below:

```
protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        //base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

        logger.DebugFormat("Configuring cryptography");
        CryptographyConfiguration cryptographyConfiguration = new CryptographyConfiguration(
            new RijndaelEncryptionProvider(
                new PassphraseKeyGenerator(Settings.DecryptedPassword, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Settings.CompanyName))
            ),
            new DefaultHmacProvider(
                new PassphraseKeyGenerator(Settings.EncryptedPassword, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Settings.SaltKey))
            )
        );

        logger.DebugFormat("Configuring forms authentication");
        FormsAuthenticationConfiguration formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
            {
                CryptographyConfiguration = cryptographyConfiguration,
                RedirectUrl = "~/",
                UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>()
            };
        FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfiguration);

        logger.DebugFormat("Configuring stateless authentication");
        StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration statelessAuthConfiguration = new StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration(ctx =>
            {
                string apiKey = string.Empty;

                if (ctx.Request.Query.ApiKey.HasValue)
                {
                    apiKey = ctx.Request.Query.ApiKey.Value;
                    logger.DebugFormat("ApiKey {0} found in the query strings", apiKey);
                }

                if (ctx.Request.Form.ApiKey.HasValue)
                {
                    apiKey = ctx.Request.Form.ApiKey.Value;
                    logger.DebugFormat("ApiKey {0} found in the form values", apiKey);
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
                    return null;

                return UserMapper.GetUserFromApiKey(apiKey, ctx);
            });
        StatelessAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, statelessAuthConfiguration);
    }
```

Comment: I've looked at the chrome cookie value and the value is exactly the same... however it doesn't seem to be recognizing it for some reason.

Comment: So the problem is i'm storing my IUserMapper class in memory on the server... so when GetUserFromIdentifier is ran it returns NULL because the collection is empty after the appdomain restarts. I need to figure out the best way to store it in a SQL table.....